# Error ffprobe and ffmpeg not found in music discord Bot Python

Tags: ffmpeg, nextcord

```
import nextcord
from nextcord.ext import commands
import yt_dlp
import asyncio

# Указываем путь к ffmpeg
ffmpeg_path = "bin/ffmpeg.exe"  # Change this to the path of your ffmpeg executable

# Создание экземпляра клиента Discord
intents = nextcord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True  # Add this line to enable message content intent
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='//', intents=intents)

# Функция для загрузки музыки
async def download_music(url, filename):
    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio',
        'outtmpl': filename + '.%(ext)s',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
        'ffmpeg_location': ffmpeg_path
    }
    with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([url])

# Команда для проигрывания музыки
@bot.command()
async def play(ctx, url):
    if not ctx.author.voice:
        await ctx.send("Вы не подключены к голосовому каналу!")
        return
    else:
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    voice_client = await voice_channel.connect()

    # Скачивание музыки
    await download_music(url, 'song')

    # Проигрывание музыки с указанием пути к ffmpeg
    voice_client.play(nextcord.PCMVolumeTransformer(nextcord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3", executable=ffmpeg_path)))

    # Удаление музыкального файла после проигрывания
    while voice_client.is_playing():
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await voice_client.disconnect()
```

Возникает следующая ошибка при попытке запустить через команду музыку - nextcord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: DownloadError: ERROR: Postprocessing: ffprobe and ffmpeg not found. Please install or provide the path using --ffmpeg-location

Пробовал путь к папке с ffmpeg, в итоге ошибка никак не выходит Пробовал переустанавливать pip, тоже разные версии ffmpeg, ничего не помогло, очень нужна помощь`